# How can I pass quoted parameters from a function to another?

Tags: bash

I'm having a little issue with a script I'm writing... let's say I have 2 functions :

```
function foo1 {
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        echo $1
        shift
    done
}

function foo2 {
    foo1 $@
}
```

My problem is the following. If I do `foo1 -o "file with space.txt"` output is

```
-o
file with space.txt
```

But with `foo2 -o "file with space.txt"` or `foo2 -o file\ with\ space.txt`, I get

```
-o
file
with
space.txt
```

Is there any way that foo1 receives "file with space.txt" from foo2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In function foo2, use double quotes:

```
foo1 "$@"
```

See `man bash` for details:

> When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2"